# tgkill Crash in Android 6.0

Tags: android, crash, android-6.0-marshmallow

In playconsole i'm having this native crash . It has been reported on only Android 6.0. with the stacktrace:

```
#00  pc 000000000006abe4  /system/lib64/libc.so (tgkill+8)
#01  pc 0000000000068374  /system/lib64/libc.so (pthread_kill+68)
#02  pc 00000000000212f8  /system/lib64/libc.so (raise+28)
#03  pc 000000000001ba98  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+60)
#04  pc 0000000000438134  /system/lib64/libart.so 
(_ZN3art7Runtime5AbortEv+324)
#05  pc 0000000000136d10  /system/lib64/libart.so 
(_ZN3art10LogMessageD2Ev+3136)
#06  pc 0000000000543014  /system/lib64/libart.so 
(artInvokeInterfaceTrampoline+1492)
#07  pc 000000000011e1e8  /system/lib64/libart.so 
(art_quick_invoke_interface_trampoline+104)
#08  pc 0000000073d16d50  /data/dalvik- 
cache/arm64/system@framework@boot.oat
```

Kindly suggest to resolve this issue.

Comment: I have same crash on Android 7.0